# Adding a word count field code for specific pages

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes, word-count

I would like to add a word count on the front page of my document, but counting only the words on page 3-10. I think I'm looking for a field code like this
{NumWords} {#Page 2-10}

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using separate documents.

1. Create the slave document slave.docx.  Add the text for page 3-10.
2. Highlight the text and set a bookmark.  Say *body*
3. On a separate line, inset the field code for numwords.  Highlight just the field code and set a bookmark.  Say **count**.  Remember not to press <kbd>F9</kbd> after you have inserted the field code otherwise it will count the field code as well, unless being off by 1 does not matter.  You can always add Appx before the word count to get around that.
4. In the master document, where you want the word count, go to the insert tab, click the dropdown on object and select **Text from file**
5. When the dialog pops up, type slave.docx in the file and then click range and type **count**
6. On page 3-10 of the master document, select **Text from file** again
7. When the dialog pops up, type slave.docx in the file and then click range and type *body*